# Check if FB.Init is done to start other scripts

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

i want to start a function after the Init is done.

```
FB.init({
    appId  : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    oauth  : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
});
```

After i done that i want to check if the Init is done and start somethink like

```
doMyFunctions();
```

But how can i check that the Init is done? If i try to start my function directly after the init i did not become data from the FB.Data.query functions.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/xocialhost/jquery.xocialCore.js/blob/master/jquery.xocialCore.js

and look at the first function.  Around line 71 is where you would put your function call.  This is wrapped in a jQuery function but if you don't use jQuery you should be able to extract the code you need from the function.